# Getting Undefined when getting .value from element

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the HTML with the bonus life span of 1:

```
    <h3>PLAYER HEALTH<span value="1" id="bonus-life" >1</span></h3>
    <progress class="playerHealth health" max="100" value="100">100%</progress>
```

Here is the JavaScript for getting the value of the span and the progress elements:

```
    const playerHealthBar = document.querySelector(".playerHealth");
    const bonusLifeEl = document.querySelector("#bonus-life");

    console.log("In index.js bonusLifeEl.innerHTML: " + bonusLifeEl.innerHTML);
    console.log(
      "In index.js - bonusLifeEl value & typeof: " +
        bonusLifeEl.value +
        " " +
        typeof bonusLifeEl.value
    );
    console.log(
      "In index.js - player health value & typeof: " +
        playerHealthBar.value +
        " " +
        typeof playerHealthBar.value
    );
```

I'm able to get the correct playerHealthBar value and typeof, but when I try that with bonus-life all I get is undefined, unless I use innerHTML then I get the "value" in the inner html.

Console log output:

```
In index.js bonusLifeEl.innerHTML: 1
index.js:8 In index.js - bonusLifeEl value & typeof: undefined undefined
index.js:14 In index.js - player health value & typeof: 100 number
```

Comment: `bonusLifeEl` is not an input, it doesn't have `.value`. The `innerHTML`  that you got on the previous line is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `input`, `select`, and certain other specific elements have a `value` property, not `span` elements. Even though you've put a `value` *attribute* on your `span`, that doesn't get reflected by a `value` property (it's also an invalid attribute for `span` elements). To put an arbitrary value on that element (other than its text content), you'd use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) and [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to retrieve it.

```
const value = bonusLifeEl.dataset.value;
```

```js
// Side note: I'd use `getElementById` rather than `querySelector` here
const bonusLifeEl = document.querySelector("#bonus-life");
const value = bonusLifeEl.dataset.value;
console.log(value,);
```

```html
<h3>PLAYER HEALTH<span data-value="1" id="bonus-life" >1</span></h3>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks so much!